# Java.lang.NullPointerException Error in Causing app crash

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, nullpointerexception, chat

This is my app code :

code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> foundDevices;
    private ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> aa;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private ListView list;
    private static int DISCOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetooth;
    private BluetoothSocket socket;
    private UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c666");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get the Bluetooth Adapter
    configureBluetooth();
    // Setup the ListView of discovered devices
    setupListView();
    // Setup search button
    setupSearchButton();
    // Setup listen button
    setupListenButton();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private void configureBluetooth() {
        bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


    }
    private void switchUI() {
        final TextView messageText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_messages);
        final EditText textEntry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_message);
        messageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textEntry.setEnabled(true);
        textEntry.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if ((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)) {
            sendMessage(socket, textEntry.getText().toString());
            textEntry.setText("");
            return true;
            }
            return false;
            }
            });


        BluetoothSocketListener bsl = new BluetoothSocketListener(socket,
        handler, messageText);
        Thread messageListener = new Thread(bsl);
        messageListener.start();
        }
    private void setupListenButton() {

        Button listenButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_listen);
        listenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent disc;
        disc = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        startActivityForResult(disc, DISCOVERY_REQUEST);
        }
        });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent
    data){
    if (requestCode == DISCOVERY_REQUEST) {
    boolean isDiscoverable = resultCode > 0;
    if (isDiscoverable) {
    String name = "bluetoothserver";
    try {
    final BluetoothServerSocket btserver =
    bluetooth.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(name, uuid);
    AsyncTask<Integer, Void, BluetoothSocket> acceptThread =
    new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, BluetoothSocket>() {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(BluetoothSocket result) {
    if (result != null)
    switchUI();
    }
    @Override
    protected BluetoothSocket doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            socket = btserver.accept(params[0]*1000);
            return socket;
            } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
    }
    };
    acceptThread.execute(resultCode);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
    }
    }
    }
    }
    private void setupListView() {
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                foundDevices);
                list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_discovered);
                list.setAdapter(aa);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int index, long arg3) {
                    AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> connectTask =
                    new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                    switchUI();
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                            BluetoothDevice device = foundDevices.get(params[0]);
                            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                            socket.connect();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.d("BLUETOOTH_CLIENT", e.getMessage());
                            }
                        return null;
                    }
                    };
                    connectTask.execute(index);
                    }
                    });
                    }



    private void setupSearchButton(){

        Button searchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_search);
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
        registerReceiver(discoveryResult,
        new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        if (!bluetooth.isDiscovering()) {
        foundDevices.clear();
        bluetooth.startDiscovery();
        }
        }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    BroadcastReceiver discoveryResult = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        BluetoothDevice remoteDevice;
        remoteDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        if (bluetooth.getBondedDevices().contains(remoteDevice)) {
        foundDevices.add(remoteDevice);
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        }
        };
        private void sendMessage(BluetoothSocket socket, String msg) {
            OutputStream outStream;
            try {
            outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            byte[] byteString = (msg + " ").getBytes();

             int[] stringAsBytes=null;
            stringAsBytes[byteString.length - 1] = 0;
            outStream.write(byteString);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH_COMMS", e.getMessage());
            }
            }
        private class MessagePoster implements Runnable {
            private TextView textView;
            private String message;
            public MessagePoster(TextView textView, String message) {
            this.textView = textView;
            this.message = message;
            }
            public void run() {
            textView.setText(message);
            }
            }
        private class BluetoothSocketListener implements Runnable {
            private BluetoothSocket socket;
            private TextView textView;
            private Handler handler;
            public BluetoothSocketListener(BluetoothSocket socket,
            Handler handler, TextView textView) {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.textView = textView;
            this.handler = handler;
            }

            public void run() {
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            try {
            InputStream instream = socket.getInputStream();
            int bytesRead = -1;
            String message = "";
            while (true) {
            message = "";
            bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
            if (bytesRead != -1) {
            while ((bytesRead==bufferSize)&&(buffer[bufferSize-1] != 0)) {
            message = message + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
            }
            message = message + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead - 1);
            handler.post(new MessagePoster(textView, message));
            socket.getInputStream();
            }
            }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH_COMMS", e.getMessage());
            }
            }
            }
}
```

Now when I run my code My app crashes giving this error :

```
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bluetoothtexting/com.example.bluetoothtexting.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:495)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at com.example.bluetoothtexting.MainActivity.setupListView(MainActivity.java:151)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at com.example.bluetoothtexting.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
10-21 13:05:24.604: E/AndroidRuntime(23046):    ... 11 more
```

Now I am not able to find out where is this error coming and how to remove this error !
It is a chatting application using Bluetooth !
Any help?

Talking about Initialisation it is being done here at this point of code :

```
BroadcastReceiver discoveryResult = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
BluetoothDevice remoteDevice;
remoteDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
if (bluetooth.getBondedDevices().contains(remoteDevice)) {
foundDevices.add(remoteDevice);
aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
};
```

Comment: it seems you have no bluetooth devices found therefore your `foundList` might be empty. You have to handle this case separately

Comment: because `foundDevices` is null

Comment: foundDevices may be null when you initializing array adpater

Comment: So how to solve this null problem ?

Comment: feed the data to list first then use it

Comment: if I initialise with `null` ?

Comment: @Pavneet Singh Data will be feed only when there is **data** !